# Can anyone help me using "Limit"

Tags: mysql, limit

What is returned by this query? Assume we have many rows in the tables.

```
Select *  
From a_bkinfo.books 
Where  isbn is not null 
Limit 200,25
```

This will display  25 rows for books where we do not have a value for the isbn attribute, correct? The first 200 rows will be filtered, but will the display show 25 rows?

Comment: What did you get when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

It will show the row 201 to less than 225 if your total rows are between 201 to 226.

If your total number of rows in database is <200 it will show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

with this query you will get those rows

```
201, 202 , 203 ,,,,,,,226
```

means from the 200 you will get the next comming 25 rows

Answer (score 1):

`limit x,y .`. here x means from which row you want to show the data y means the count after the xth row how many rows you want to show..

`limit x` means it will show first x rows of your database table

Answer (score 0):

It will show the `maximum of 25` or the number of` results after 200th row

Answer (score 0):

This query will display 25 rows of information which do not have a `null` value for `isbn`, starting with the 200th row in the query.

***If*** there are less than 25 rows that match the query after the first 200 rows (i.e., < 225 total), you'll only receive the remaining results in the response.

Answer (score 0):

That query will skip the first 200 matching rows and yield the next 25. If there are less than 225 rows in the resultset you might get anywhere from 0 to 24 results.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in LIMIT is the offset, the second is the max. number of results. So this will display up to 25 entries, skipping the first 200.
Keep in mind that mysql starts counting at 0, not at 1.